# Mesh does not follow armature

Tags: mesh, armature

[image]So I've made a pretty fancy hand, that I want to attach to an armature. The thing is, I've tried everything, but the mesh doesn't want to follow the armature. I've removed the double verticles (I had 8) and watched lots of tutorials, but I just can't fix it, at least it looks like. I'm not new at Blender. I'm working on models for a game, but I never tried to use a single armature. I'm new on the forum, but I'll try to add the .blend file, and if you have time, and you feel helping me, you could try to make the mesh follow the armature, because I'm st*pid for it right now, but I'm trying. Yet I'm not planning to do any animations for it, just want to move the fingers the correct way.

PS: If we finish the game and you keep helping us, you may get displayed on the credits. If you want to help us contact me on Skype, and I send you the file: szabo.jozsef501

Here is the link for the model: http://www.mediafire.com/download/dwh3bvw5rir4d5w/HandV2.blend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you used NGons the bad way.
[image: ngons1]
[image: ngons2]

Everything is fine after triangulation of the faces (Edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select all <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and "triangulate faces" in the face menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
[image: face menu]
Recalculate normals (all selected and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
Back in object mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select the mesh <kbd>RClick</kbd>, then the armature with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RClick</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose "armature deform"/"with automatic weights"
Then parenting the hand to the armatures works fine.
[image: fine!]

Comment: So, I'm done with that triangulation, and I'm parented the hand to the armature, but still not following. Did I missed something? I'm in the noob stage of this armature thing, so can you please make a step by step "tutorial" with pictures? I've made a printscreen about my parenting. I can't share a picture on this comment, so I attach one to the question.

Comment: recalculate normals (Ctrl+N) after triangulation and then parent armature

Comment: Thanks man! You saved me from 48 hours of YouTube searching. You're the best!

Comment: glad to help :) have fun!